# Preparing Mixed States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator

Let's say we want to obtain a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ 50% in the $|0 \rangle$ and 50% in the $|1 \rangle$ state with density matrix $\rho=\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{1}$.

I am well aware that by creating the $0^{th}$ Bell with 2 Qubits, then each individual Qubit will be in the mixed state I have described above since:

$$\text{Tr}_B\Big( \Big( \frac{|00 \rangle+|11 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \Big) \Big( \frac{\langle 00 |+\langle11 |}{\sqrt{2}} \Big)  \Big ) = \frac{1}{2} \Big( |0\rangle \langle0| +  |1\rangle \langle1| \Big) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{1}$$

Is there a more direct way of creating the mixed state, without introducing entanglement with another Qubit?

Comment: Take unpolarized light, or the output of a Stern-Gerlach oven.  You get $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\vert \uparrow \rangle+\frac{1}{2}\vert\downarrow \rangle$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Won't work with light, unless you have an unpolarized single photon source.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I had in mind a regular incandescent light bulb.

Comment: This will not produce a maximally mixed state of one qubit, I suspect. Also a light bulb will have some coherence between the photons, I'd suspect. Also, you won't get individual qubits in a maximally mixed state.